# DIV swap onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to implement a content locking system to my site and as part of it would like to lock out an on-site mp3 player until the user has completed an offer.

So when the page loads it shows the player, but if they try to click on it, it pops up the content locker and once they've completed an offer it swaps the DIV for the fully usable player.

here's the code:

```
<div id="mobmp3">
    <div id="yoursecDiv" style="display:block; z-index: 999;">  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://c.themixtapesite.com/locker.js?guid=0512eafd69b18d22');document.body.appendChild(fileref); setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);"> 
                                            <iframe src="http://themixtapesite.com/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-cloud-mp3-player/html5/html5mob2.php?bucket=mixtape2" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" width="97.4%" height="280" max-width="97.4%">
                                            </iframe>
                                    </a>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- Place the Real Link within yourfirDiv which is set to not display
until yourFunction has been executed. -->
<div id="yourfirDiv" style="display:none;">
    <iframe src="http://themixtapesite.com/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-cloud-mp3-player/html5/html5mob2.php?bucket=mixtape2"
    frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" width="97.4%"
    height="280" max-width="97.4%"></iframe>
</div>
```

So, as you can see, i'm trying to load up an iframe (the player) within `yoursecDiv`. then once they've completed the offer it reloads `yourfirDiv` which is the same player but without the content locker.

I was hoping by wrapping the `<iframe>` in the `<a>` tag i would achieve this, but alas, it doesn't work.

So i guess my question is:
Is there a way i can overlay a div (or something) over the iframe to act as the link to open the content locker?

Comment: Can you not show one div (the locker) and when you want to enable that, use jQuery to hide the div and show the player? Wouldn't this be easy to get around though just by looking at the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is now solved... after a bit of fresh air my brain started working and i simply used a transparent gif that i overlayed over the div. then set that gif as the trigger link.

Comment: This would be damn easy to get around by people who know even a little about web development though, i.e. you could just open firebug, find the div or transparent gif or whatever your 'content blocker' is and just delete the element. If its not vital and you don't mind a few people like us doing this then this isn't problem!